# Proton Drive file renaming and data duplication issue

Tags: sync, batch-rename, cloud-storage, files-folders, user-experience

I use Proton Drive to backup some of my data, and at one point when I was trying to restructure the directories within my Proton Drive account I found, some hours later after I had awoken, that Proton Drive had not only renamed seemingly every single file out of 860 GB, but it had also started duplicating all of that data. I stopped it after it had duplicated about 60 GB, but enough damage had been done.

I emailed Proton Tech Support and they basically said thanks for the information, we have shared it with our developers, but there is nothing that we can do to help you. This is pretty much what I expected from them. Unfortunately I do not have a version of the data that exists prior to this issue. I have already started manually perusing each folder and deleting all redundant files, but there are thousands of them, and far too many for this to really be a practical approach. As I now understand it Proton Drive simply does not "sync" a user's data the way, or at all, that I previously thought it did.

**Essentially the problem as I see it is this:**
I need to delete the duplicated data (That part is much easier), and I need to rename all the files across all the directories that have had the following appended to their file names: (# Name clash "Date of the Incident" "RandomUniqueAlphaNumericString" #).
Any help would be appreciated, but I am not hopeful that there is anyway to make this less painful. I have already looked at the mass renaming features of command prompt, but that mostly seems to only apply to individual directories and naming schemes that are sequential.

Unfortunately, perhaps, I am in no way a computer programmer, and I do not possess the skill set to create a custom script or application in order to solve this issue.

My system is Windows 10, and is fully updated as of the date of this post.

Comment: There isn't really a trick to this. You just have to do it. Also, if the duplicated data is only duplicated in the Proton drive cloud, this question is off topic here. If the duplicated data is also duplicated on your computer, that is the part we can help with. Use the EDIT button to make that all more clear.

Comment: Sorry but this comment seems entirely like a non sequitur. I have never felt nor indicated that there was a "trick" to anything. I have in fact already done it. All of the duplicated data was on my computer, and while my post does not state that explicitly, it is definitely implied, and the further comments seem to me to confirm that...? Lastly I stated yesterday that finished solving this problem. I also provided an update with a brief summary of both what I did and expressed my gratitude to those who assisted me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after working on this for the last couple days I have successfully finished correcting the problem. Through a combination of Windows File Explorer Search, Sort, and Group functions I was able to isolate the redundant files, and through the use of BRU plus some creative, temporary moves of some folders I was able to successfully rename everything properly. Cheers, and thanks BRU dev team! Also thanks to DrMoishe Pippik for his invaluable recommendation to use BRU!

Comment: I realize that I have solved this issue, provided an explanation of what I did to solve it, and marked it as solved, but it seems to have been closed due to being "off-topic." Is anyone able to explain why that is? There really weren't any hardware concerns here, but all of the concerns were quite clearly indicated by me throughout this thread to be software concerns local to my personal machine. There are several points where I mention the various software I used, for instance: Windows File Explorer, Command Prompt, and my use of Bulk Rename Utility which Dr.MoishePippik recommended.

Answer (score 1):

There are various applications to batch rename files, such as [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/), , and many [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-rename-utility/), free and paid.

If the *original* filenames did not have the symbol **#** (AKA number sign, pound sign), and the appended text always *begins* with **#**, then the task to rename then looks fairly straightforward:

- In each filename, search for the incidence of **#**.
- Trim the filename, so all that is left is the string up until that character.

However, there are two important *caveats:*

- **Back up the data before renaming files.** A mistake made in the process could lose many, if not all files. Back them up to an external drive, not just the cloud.
- **Test** renaming *copies*, first one one file, then a few files in the same folder, before running the task on *all*.

You might need to write a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex), and regex syntax may differ amongst the tools. The task is to select all characters up to but not including the **#** symbol, and rename the file to that string. If you are having difficulty, show what you've tried and the application your using in another question.

Comment: Hello there, sir, and thank you for your assistance. I have now successfully isolated all of the files that need to be renamed as well as created multiple backups of all of the data (both the separated redundant data and the complete directory of the main data that still needs to be renamed)

I have investigated, and started using BRU as you suggested, and it seems to be a promising tool for this problem. I seem to have run into a snag though as it continues to give me errors that I suspect are due to long path names. I have already changed the Long Path settings (a long time ago) in Windows

Comment: So after further testing I am no longer certain that BRU is having difficulty due to long path names. It seems possible that it is just mis-identifying certain files, and at least in some cases classifying them as folders. In the test I am working on right now for instance there is an HTML file that it is failing to see when I have the Filters set so that 'Files' and 'Subfolders' are checked and 'Folders' is unchecked. I am not sure if it is a bug...

Comment: In the BRU log file I get the following error:

"Error: The system cannot find the path specified."

After further testing and examination I am still not sure as to the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: I also just realized that since I will be using BRU to simply remove the last 36 characters from ALL of the filenames in all of the subdirectories, and excluding all folders, I also need to exclude all files that have been added to any of the relevant folders between December 25, 2023 and the present. All of the files prior to that date need to be renamed, and all of the files that were redundant and have now been isolated were created on December 24, 2023.